# Monitor the CPU usage of an OpenFOAM simulation running on a slurm job

Tags: openmpi, slurm, openfoam

I'm running an OpenFOAM simulation on a cluster. I have used [the Scotch decomposition method](https://cfd.direct/openfoam/user-guide/running-applications-parallel/) and my `decomposeParDict` looks like this:

```
FoamFile
{
    version     2.0;
    format      ascii;
    class       dictionary;
    object      decomposeParDict;
}
numberOfSubdomains 6;
method          scotch;
```

`checkMesh` and `decomposePar` finish with no issues. I have assigned 6 nodes to the slurm by

```
srun -N6 -l sonicFoam
```

and the solver runs smoothly without any errors.

The issue is the solution **speed is not improved** in comparison to the non-parallel simulation I ran before. I want to monitor the CPU usage to see if all of the 6 nodes I have assigned are similarly loaded. The `squeue --user=foobar` command return the `jobNumber` and list of nodes assigned (`NODELIST(REASON)`) which looks like this:

```
foo,bar[061-065]
```

from `sinfo` command these nodes are both in `debug` and `main*` `PARTITION`s  (which I have absolutely no idea what it means!).

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24087711/4999991) says that you can use the `sacct` or `sstat` commands to monitor CPU time and memory usage of a slurm job. But when I run

```
sacct --format="CPUTime,MaxRSS"
```

it gives me:

```
 CPUTime     MaxRSS
---------- ----------
  00:00:00
  00:00:00
  00:07:36
  00:00:56
  00:00:26
  15:26:24
```

which I can not understand. And when I specify the job number by

```
sacct --job=<jobNumber> --format="UserCPU"
```

The return is empty. So my questions are

- Is my simulation loading all nodes or is it running on one or two and the rest are free?
- am I running the right commands? if yes what those numbers mean? how they represent the CPU usage per node?
- If not then what are the right `--format="..."`s for `sacct` and/or `sstat` (or maybe other slurm commands) to get the CPU usage/load?

**P.S.1.** I have followed the OpenFOAM compiling following [the official instructions](https://www.openfoam.com/code/build-guide.php). I did not do anything with `OpenMPI` and it's `mpicc` compiler for that matter though.

**P.S.2** For those of you who might end up here. Maybe I'm running the wrong command apparently one can first allocate some resources by:

```
srun -N 1 --ntasks-per-node=7 --pty bash
```

where 7 is the number of cores you want and bash is just a name. and then run the solver with:

```
mpirun -np 7 sonicFoam -parallel -fileHandler uncollated
```

I'm not sure yet though.

Comment: if you can SSH to the compute nodes when your simulation is running, you can simply log in and use the `top` command to figure out whether a process is present and running. you can also `pstack <pid>` to check where it is.

Comment: would you please elaborate on this? how can I get the ip address of the nodes?

Comment: `squeue` lists the nodes allocated to the job when it is running, then you can simply SSH to them by hostname.

Comment: but how do I find the hostname of those specific nodes?

Comment: one job with 6 nodes, you can either try a smaller job or repeat the operation on all 6 of them.

Comment: I can't afford try and error as each simulation takes days to finish :(

Comment: no problem, good luck then !

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
sacct --format='jobid,AveCPU,MinCPU,MinCPUTask,MinCPUNode'
```

to check whether all CPUs have been active. Compare `AveCPU` (average CPU time of all tasks in job) with `MinCPU` (minimum CPU time of all tasks in job). If they are equal, all 6 tasks (you requested 6 nodes, with, implicitly, 1 task per node) worked equally. If they are not equal, or even `MinCPU` is zero, then some tasks have been doing nothing.

But in your case, I believe you will observe that all tasks have been working hard, but they were all doing the same thing.

Besides the remark concerning the `-parallel` flag by @timdykes, you also must be aware that launching an MPI job with `sun` requires that OpenMPI was compiled with Slurm support. During your installation of OpenFOAM, it installed its own version of OpenMPI, and if file `/usr/include/slurm/slurm.h` or `/usr/include/slurm.h` exists, then Slurm support was probably compiled in. But the safest is probably to use `mpirun`.

But to do that, you will have to first request an allocation from Slurm with either `sbatch` or `salloc`.

Comment: Thanks for the post. I tried the `sacct --format='jobid,AveCPU,MinCPU,MinCPUTask,MinCPUNode'` and all the fields are empty! would you please elaborate on 1. how to make sure the OpenMPI on my systems was compiled with Slurm? you may note that I don't have admin privileges of course. 2. I checked and `/usr/include/slurm/slurm.h` exists but I don't think it was installed with my OpenFOAM. 3. what is the correct way of running `mpirun` with `sbatch` and salloc? can you give an example please?

Comment: I might mean that accounting was not configured in Slurm. What is the output of `scontrol show config | grep JobAcctGatherType`?

Comment: 1. OpenFOAM does not use the pre-installed OpenMPI, it comes with its own version, that gets compiled when you run `./Allwmake `. So somewhere, in your OpenFOAM directory, must be an OpenMPI directory, and a `config.log` with details of how OpenMPI was compiled.

Comment: `scontrol show config | grep JobAcctGatherType` -->  `JobAcctGatherType       = jobacct_gather/none`

Comment: 2. No indeed it was not installed with your OpenFOAM, it was installed with Slurm. But your OpenFOAM must have picked it when being compiled.

Comment: 3. Interactive option: `salloc -N6 <ENTER> mpirun sonicFoam`. Batch option: `sbatch -N6 --wrap "mpirun sonicFoam"`

Comment: sorry if my questions seem premivitive. I am very new to the whole slurm/MPI/OpenFOAM world. Should I compile my OpenFOAM again to be sure it is using the preinstalled slurm-OpenMPI? how should I do that?!

Comment: `jobacct_gather/none` means the information is not collected I am afraid.

Comment: No, it is preferable to use the OpenFOAM-provided OpenMPI. Stick to using `mpirun` rather than `srun` and it should be fine.

Comment: in `salloc -N6 <ENTER> mpirun sonicFoam` what is the `<ENTER>` entry?

Comment: it means hit the Enter key

Comment: I'm trying the `sbatch -N6 --wrap "mpirun sonicFoam"` it runs, but still no way to tell if I'm using all the nodes/CPUs equally!

Comment: For that, you will have to peek into the OpenFAOM output logs and see whether it split the work or not. But that is out of my area of expertise I am afraid

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried running with the '-parallel' argument? All of the OpenFOAM examples online use this argument when running a parallel job, one example is the [official guide](https://www.openfoam.com/documentation/user-guide/running-applications-parallel.php) for running in parallel.

```
srun -N $NTASKS -l sonicFOAM -parallel
```

As an aside - I saw you built openfoam yourself, have you checked whether the cluster admins have provided a module for it? You can usually run `module avail` to see a list of the available modules, and then `module load moduleName` if there is an existing OpenFOAM module. This is useful as you can probably trust its been built with all the right options and would automatically set up your $PATH etc.

Comment: thanks for the post: 1. I tried the `module avail` and there are no OpenFOAM modules available. Not expected. this server is meant for a neural network guys and I'm kinda abusing it for CFD :) 2. I was not aware of the `-parallel` flag as it was not mentioned in [the official page for OpenFOAM parallelization](https://cfd.direct/openfoam/user-guide/running-applications-parallel/). I will try it now. 3. [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bHMdh_l45M0) I see that I must run the code with `mpirun`. I am gonna try that too. but still no way to compare them as I can't monitor CPUs.

Comment: I checked: 1. `mpirun -np 6 sonicFoam -parallel` works but still no way to tell if it is harvesting all 6 nodes/CPUS. 2. A little weird but this also runs `srun -N6 -l mpirun -np 6 sonicFoam -parallel` also runs! 3. `srun -N6 -l sonicFoam -parallel` leads to a very long cryptic error which I can not comprehend. maybe I can log it and post into a new question.

Comment: In regards to 2. while the argument isnt mentioned explicitly in the text, you can see it used in the example in 3.2.3, and a brief google search for 'OpenFOAM example slurm' shows many examples all of which use the -parallel flag. For 3. You need to use whichever MPI launch wrapper is appropriate for your machine, if it is a cluster with SLURM (looks like it) then srun is probably the most appropriate command. If not sure, you should check with your administators (probably you have a 'Getting Started' guide for the cluster that explains the appropriate usage for MPI jobs?).

Comment: I have not gogled `OpenFOAM` and `slurm` together yet. gonna do that now. and come back with the results. thanks for the hint.