# how to get cputime and wait time in slurm job manager after completion of job

Tags: jobs, hpc, slurm

I submitted job to slurm and my job completed successfully.

After one hour/10 mins, i want to know the cpu time and wait time of my job?

How to know that ??

Please help me 
suchetan

Comment: Duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24020420/find-out-the-cpu-time-and-memory-usage-of-a-slurm-job

Comment: That giving CPUTime what about wait Time. ? and also sacct cputime is changing even after completion so i got doubt on sacct output .[suparikshan@master]$ date
Fri Oct 12 16:58:25 IST 2018
3278             richa 36193-11:56:16
3663            sajeed 608-12:14:14
3664            sajeed 608-12:10:18
3665            shweta 8519-02:17:40
Fri Oct 12 16:59:38 IST 2018
3278             richa 36193-14:08:48
3663            sajeed 608-12:16:36
3664            sajeed 608-12:12:40
3665            shweta 8519-02:50:48