# slurm: produce stats job in log files

Tags: cluster-computing, hpc, slurm

I use `slurm` to run jobs on a cluster. I would like to get stats about the job, such as used memory, number of processors and wall-time. I would like to get such information in the log file. I think that this was possible with `LSF` (if I remember correctly and I am not getting confused with some other platform).

Answer (score 2):

You can get this information from the Slurm database, see https://slurm.schedmd.com/sacct.html or [Find out the CPU time and memory usage of a slurm job](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24020420/6352677). E.g. `sacct  --jobs=12345 --format=NCPUS,MaxRSS,CPUTime`.

Note: you can add this to the epilog script. Here is an example of `epilog.srun`:

```
#!/bin/sh
TMPDIR="/local"

# Append job usage info to job stdout
stdoutfname=`scontrol show job ${SLURM_JOB_ID} --details | grep "StdOut=" | sed -e 's/.*StdOut=\([^\s][^\s]*\)/\1/'`

if [ -w "${stdoutfname}" ] && [ "${QTMPDIR}" != "" ]; then
  sacct --format JobID,jobname,AveCPUFreq,AveDiskRead,AveRSS,cputime,MaxDiskWrite  -j ${SLURM_JOB_ID} >> ${stdoutfname}
```

Alternatively, you can use `/usr/bin/time -v <your command>` inside of your script (with full path for `time`, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/774601/6352677). That will be in the logs, but will not exactly match Slurm's accounting values.