# Find CPU and Memory Time Series of Slurm Job?

Tags: memory, out-of-memory, slurm

There's a nice question ([Find out the CPU time and memory usage of a slurm job](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24020420/find-out-the-cpu-time-and-memory-usage-of-a-slurm-job)) about how to retrieve the CPU time and memory usage of a slurm job and spinup has a nice answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/56555505/4570472). However, if I understand correctly, `seff <job id>` returns `Memory Efficiency` which corresponds to MAXRSS over the entire life of the job.

How do I retrieve the time series of memory (and perhaps CPU) usage?

I'd like this to understand why my slurm jobs are running out of memory after 6+ hours of running fine.

Comment: Whenever I've had to do this, I added a loop in my script that printed memory and cpu usage (using `psutil` for python) to a file.